# parsing error in smartcontract constructor

Tags: npm, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

[image]

parsing error in smartcontract constructor, can some one please help me out and show me what I am doing wring and why this error is even thought everytrhing is looking fine from outside.

Comment: its post, its the token symbol, of erc721 which i want to give to this contract.

Comment: you need use `"post"` instead of `post`

Comment: normally for token symbol that is not required, I have seen other contracts they are just like this, but still let me try to pass in this format you suggested.

Comment: https://ibb.co/CMpZ2cQ  now this is the error, please check the image

Comment: that is warning, so, that is no problem

Comment: https://ibb.co/9vPfCMz  seems the warning is gone when I remove the parameters from the constructor.  let me try to compile

Comment: sure, if the params is no used, then, we can remove that

Comment: yes git it compiles thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor ERC721 need two string arguments(name and symbol) so you need to write like this

```
ERC721("Cryptopost","post")
```

so replace line 16 by this :

```
constructor(string memory token, string memory symbol)ERC721("Cryptopost","post")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the erc721 openzeppelin file before creating the smart contract? For example:

```
//Import goes here
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

//this is the constructor function 
constructor() public ERC721("Name", "symbol") {}
```